# org-cycle (from CHILDREN TO SUBTREE when SUBTREE is empty)

Tags: emacs, org-mode, folding

When I am using `org-cycle` it annoys me when I have to execute a redundant `org-cycle` when the *SUBTREE* is empty.

```
- list A

    - sub_list A
```

Here `org-cycle` goes from *FOLDED* to *CHILDREN* then to *SUBTREE*, yet there's nothing to show. Is there a way to go back to *FOLDED* state when the subtree is empty?

Comment: I would guess that the check might be expensive (imagine a headline with a million children - checking that all the subtrees are empty, so you can avoid the extra call, is probably not worth it). But `org-cycle` is bound to TAB exactly so that it can be easily invoked. Are you objecting to pressing TAB one more time than necessary?

Comment: Yes. It's a mere trifle that I would prefer solving. If it's a necessary evil, then shall it be.